# How to get the data between mth and nth occurrence in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using a SQL Server query to fetch the column information. But I need some information which is after 3rd and 4th occurrence in that particular column

Here is my sample data

```
[xxxxxxx||gh||vbh||CAPACITY_CPU||aed]
[qwe34||asdf||qwe||CONNECTIVITY||ghj]
[ertgfy||fgv||yuhjj||ACCESS||rty]
[tyhuj||rtg||qwert||ACCESS||TMW]
```

I'm looking for the data information after 3rd and 4th occurrence of `||`

Something like

```
Capacity_CPU
CONNECTIVITY
ACCESS
```

My source column is not specific length, it will vary in the length

Comment: Where are you using this? PHP, Java, C# etc etc?

Comment: It's tagged as SQL and mentions MS SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Use [PATINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

create regex for the column that you need, then use `SUBSTRING` to extract the string that you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use mixture of SUBSTRING, CHARINDEX, LEFT AND RIGHT Function. The best solution is you have to play with this function.

```
      `
                Create table #t( Name varchar(200))

            Insert into #t
            values
            ('[xxxxxxx||gh||vbh||CAPACITY_CPU||aed]'),
            ('[qwe34||asdf||qwe||CONNECTIVITY||ghj]'),
            ('[ertgfy||fgv||yuhjj||ACCESS||rty]'),
            ('[tyhuj||rtg||qwert||ACCESS||TMW]') 

            Select * from #t

            Select 
            name,
            Right(LEFT(name,len(name)-6),charindex('||',reverse(LEFT(name,len(name)-7))))
            From #t
      `
```

Comment: here my text string is not limited. its not limited to have 3 characters after last occurance of ||. its keep on changing.

Answer (score 0):

1) Instead of trying to do such operations with those strings you could normalize database by designing and adding a new table. In this case, you would need a simple SELECT:

```
SELECT Column4
FROM dbo.Table;
```

2) Otherwise, one solution is to convert those strings into XML and to use `nodes` and `value` XML methods:

```
DECLARE @Source NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @Source = 
N'[xxxxxxx||gh||vbh||CAPACITY_CPU||aed]
[qwe34||asdf||qwe||CONNECTIVITY||ghj]
[ertgfy||fgv||yuhjj||ACCESS||rty]
[tyhuj||rtg||qwert||ACCESS||TMW]';

DECLARE @EncodedSource NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @EncodedSource = (SELECT @source FOR XML PATH(''));

DECLARE @x XML;
SET @x = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@EncodedSource, N'[', N'<row> <col>'), N']', N'"</col> </row>'), N'||', N'</col> <col>');

SELECT  r.XmlContent.value('(col[1]/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS Col1,
        r.XmlContent.value('(col[4]/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS Col4
FROM    @x.nodes('/row') r(XmlContent);
```

Note: you need to replace `NVARCHAR(length)` with the proper data type and max. length.